# Unable to install criterion package

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

When I attempt to install the criterion package I get the following error message: *error: #error Unsupported OS/architecture/compiler!*. I believe the fix is here: [Restore support for 32 bit Intel CPUs](https://github.com/bos/criterion/pull/105/commits/fb794484bcf7c88b1b3d5f7fb33c356742f4d31f) . However how do I install that fix?

Comment: With an error message like this it would be really helpful to know what os compiler and so on you use

Comment: os is Windows 7 32 bit. Compiler is GHC ver 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

As I can tell from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.4.0/src/cbits/cycles.c, v1.1.4.0 includes the fix you linked to.

To use that version or a later one, add a lower bound to your dependency on `criterion`:

```
build-depends:
  ...
  , criterion >= 1.1.4.0
  ...
```